# R Shiny - output name based on function input

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

In the server-part, I have multiple outputs like:

```
output$cityname_plot1 <- renderPlot({.......})
output$cityname_plot2 <- renderPlot({.......})
output$cityname_plot3 <- renderPlot({.......})
```

Now I want to put this into a function, so that I can use it for multiple cities.

How can I change the output-name, based on an input coming from the function? I want to change the cityname part. I thought if something like this:

```
createCity(cityName){
paste0('output$',cityname,'_plot1') <- renderPlot({.......})
paste0('output$',cityname,'_plot2') <- renderPlot({.......})
paste0('output$',cityname,'_plot3') <- renderPlot({.......})
```

}

That obviously does not work. I have read about modulizing, but I dont get it.

How do I do it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you planning to show all those plots in parallel or is the user able to switch between plots?

Comment: the user will be able to switch between plots. they are displayed on seperate menuitems

Comment: Than I guess it makes sense to use one `plotOutput` per `menuItem` and change the underlying data instead of creating a separate `plotOutput` for each city in your dataset. Please share a reproducible example.

Comment: Well, I have menuitems for each city and each plot. I.E. for City 1 Plot 1, City 1 Plot 2, City 2 Plot 1 etc etc.... I think that wont work. I will share a reproductible example soon.

Comment: To me that doesn't seem very user friendly. Why don't you use `selectizeInput`'s to switch between city / plot. However, let's see your example first.

Comment: The menuitems are nescessary to reduce complexity. The 4 cities are our main projects and each of the plots is one important kpi. I also have 3 inputs for the plots, which change the underlying data. So 4 cities and 9 Plots per city. Thats why I wanted to combine all cities in one function.